# Boolean function to check for leaf properties

Tags: tree, scheme, depth-first-search

Consider a Tree such that each node contains an integer. In scheme the Tree datatype can then be defined as

```
(define-type Tree
    [leaf (val : number)]
    [node (val : number)
          (left : Tree)
          (right : Tree)])
```

I would like to write a function that given one such tree, returns #t if  every leaf is bigger than the sum of numbers in the path of nodes from the root that reaches the leaf.

The way I am thinking of going about this is for each leaf compare its number with every sum from the leaf to the root (i.e. compute the sum along every path from the leaf to the root). The first path for which the leaf number is smaler or equal to the path sum leads me to return #f. Otherwise I have to search every single path.
Is this the most efficient way of going about it?
Is depth first search the best way to implement this strategy?

Comment: If it's a tree then surely there's only one path to each leaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most convenient way is straightforward tree recursion, i.e. depth-first, using a parameter to store "the sum so far".

Pseudocode:

```
(define (all-greater tree sum)
    (if the tree is a leaf 
        (> (val of tree) sum)
        (and (all-greater (left subtree of tree) (+ sum (val of tree)))
             (all-greater (right subtree of tree) (+ sum (val of tree))))))


(define (all-greater? tree) (all-greater tree 0))
```